# how to create a file of mysql database schema?

Tags: mysql, database

I need some help about how to dump only database schema, not the data.

Our database already has data.But i want to create a database 
dump only for schema with out data.

I think mysqldump dumps schema along with data. 
Are there any options i can specify which will let me to dump schema without data.

Comment: create database and create table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqldump --no-data DATABASENAME

Or use MysqlAdministrator, phpMyAdmin or any other tool.

Comment: Correct to use mysqldump, wrong to use phpmyadmin. phpmyadmin is in my experience not something which should be used, ever. It is too buggy and has some bugs which will trash your data.

Comment: Never come accross this - what bugs do you think of exactly?